# How do you like to format rectangle coordinates for output?

Tags: terminology

What is the best/clearest way to format the coordinates of a rectangle for diagnostic output?   What tricks can I use to make it easy for someone reading the output to quickly figure out if the coordinates are a **X/Y/Width/Height** vs. a **Left/Top/Right/Bottom**?

Sounds like a mundane question, but this has been making crazy for years!

A format I've seen before is something like **+100,+300,500,500** on X11, where the +/- are meant to imply that the first two digits are X/Y, since Width/Height cannot be negative values (where as with Left/Top/Right/Bottoms any of the values can be either positive or negative).

While on the topic, what do we even call a left/top/right/bottom? WPF Calls this type 
"Thickness".

Answer (score 1):

The best representation is the most descriptive one. In other words, if you're going to list it, make sure you include the description somewhere. Sorry this doesn't point to a specific formula, but I hope it helps.

Examples:

- (x1,y1)(x2,y2) = (10,20)(50,14)
- L/T/R/B = 10/20/50/14
- X/Y/Width/Height = 10/20/40/6

Answer (score 1):

i usually use:

```
100,150(50x19)
```

the `x` for the size makes it obvious that it is width & height as opposed to right & bottom

Answer (score 0):

If you are in control of the output I would suggest you use x1=, y1=, x2=, y2=, to indicate point-coordinates, and x=, y=, w=, h=, to indicate size-coordinates.

Alternatively:
[x1,y1]-[x2,y2] for point-coordinates
[x,y,w,h] for size-coordinates
e.g.: [10,10]-[100,100]
and:  [10, 10, 90, 90]
would indicate the 'same' rectangle, and using square-brackets would indicate rectangles as opposed to lines (in the first case)

Comment: Clearly this will be very unambiguous, but this format uses a lot of room, and when I look at it, all I see are the = signs.